# Power Button Press - Keep screen on

Tags: android, android-intent, screen

In my application I need to capture Power Button Press in an activity, and then show another activity. I have already managed to catch the power button and to show new activity when it is pressed. 
I use BroadcastReceiver, to hook on the power press event. I added following flags to my Activity in order to prevent the screen from being locked when the power button is pressed:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);//prevent phone from being locked    
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); //I am not sure it works.    
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);//turns the screen on
```

Although I can catch the power press and show the activity without being locked out, the screen turns off for about 1 second and the turns on automatically again, that is not what I really want. 
Is there anyway I can keep the screen on when user presses the power button?

I could not catch power by dispatchkeyevent, but i could catch it by this:

```
screenoff = new BroadcastReceiver()
public static final String Screenoff = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(Screenoff)) {
            //code goes here return;

        return;
        }
    };
    IntentFilter offfilter = new IntentFilter (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(screenoff, offfilter);
```

The problem is that the screen off for about 1 second.
Why this happens and how I can fix that?

Thanks,
Hossein

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
boolean     dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
Called to process key events.
```

in the Activity class to capture key events instead.

Not sure if it catches the Power Button though.

Comment: I coud already catch the event by broadcastreceiver but the screen off for 1 second or so and I want to prevent that. Is there any way to keep the screen on, even when the user press power? I also have tried 'getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);' but I did not help me too.